# How to set and check cookies wih JAX-RS in a java library code

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, setcookie

I am a noobie with RESTful API and I am trying to build a java library which gets an authentication token using a REST call and then I intend to store it in a cookie so that I can use it for further API calls. I have done it using the following code:

How can this be achieved?

```
NewCookie cookie4 = new NewCookie("name", "123");
Response.ok("OK").cookie(cookie4).build();
//call made to retrieve the cookie here, is defined below
```

I have a get cookie method like so

```
  @GET
    public Response getCookie(@CookieParam("name") Cookie cookie) {
            if (cookie == null) {
                System.out.println("IN NULL");
                return Response.serverError().entity("ERROR").build();
            } else {
                return Response.ok(cookie.getValue()).build();
            }
    }
```

Now I try to retrieve the cookie after I set it above :

```
  Cookie cookieval = null;
    Response check = getCookie(cookieval);
    System.out.println(cookieval.getName());
    System.out.println(cookieval.getValue());
```

It does not work, the flow goes into cookie null part in the above getcookie method. I am testing it using a JUNIT test case. the cookie is only persistent with a request object not otherwise

Please let me know if the information is inadequate or need more information

Comment: If it's a test case, please post _complete_ runnable code example.

Answer (score 0):

I saw your code and looks like the problem is the first line where you declare cookieval as "null" and then you pass a null value to the method getCookie who recognize it as null.

```
Cookie cookieval = null;
Response check = getCookie(cookieval);
System.out.println(cookieval.getName());
System.out.println(cookieval.getValue());
```